# Fetch more than one word in a column using the first letter only

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need a simple answer, thank you.

- MY DATABASE -- I have a column with the name keywords. Inside I have a list of words that are keywords from a title (see example below)

column (title) --- all red apples / column (keywords) --- apple red tree

column (title) --- the apple fell / column (keywords) --- red leaf fell

So the title column has (the apple fell)
the keywords column has red leaf fell
 - my first question is in mysql database, I need to know when entering more than one word inside a column do I need a *comma* or a *space*?

This answer will help me code correctly and I can go into my database and set it up correctly!

PHP CODING QUESTION - **what I need to know is how to retrieve a word or words from my column keywords that start with the letter a inside those rows.**

I would like all the words that start with the letter a from each keywords row to appear.

I can pull the first word apple using WHERE keywords LIKE('a%'), however I cannot get the second or other words after the first word listed under my keywords column.

SO EXAMPLE KEYWORDS ARE

keywords column row one ---- bell ring apple

keywords column row two ---- art words leaf

keywords column row three ---- books all read

I need all the words that start with the letter a from all three columns. Can anyone please give me a code that works with the WHERE clause on how to fetch the words starting with the letter a in all rows under the keywords column.

Thank you very much.

P.S. I have attached a picture on my keywords column. The keywords are different then listed here, but the request is still the same. [keywords picture from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH2Ty.png)

Comment: can you please narrow down your question only keeping the gist?

Answer (score 1):

For get the word in keywords column use

```
SELECT * from <table> WHERE keywords LIKE ? ORDER BY keywords ASC
```

So if change ? with %A% give you a complete list with all the keywords that start with A.

this is an example with prepared statement

```
$term_sql = $conn->prepare(" SELECT * from table WHERE keywords LIKE ? ORDER BY keywords ASC");
$term_sql->bind_param('s', $key);
```

Comment: Oh thank you for your comment, yes when I did applied that coding it did work however it pulled every word with the letter a located inside the word. -----------------------------  SO MY Code    $query = "SELECT keywords, title, link, datesimple FROM articles WHERE keywords LIKE('%a%') ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT $start_from, $record_per_page";  ----------------------------------- if you look at my picture there is a word quran and it pulled this title because it has the letter a in it. Is there a way to narrow down where it only pulls the first letter only from each word, thank you

Comment: glad to helped you ! :)

Comment: if fixed the problem please confirm my answer with thanks!

Comment: here is an example of my page. I do not want the title -----  Jesus in the Quran? What do you say? 11-24-2013 in with the list. All the others are correct (dummy examples)--------------- http://livinghisword.org/php/articles/a.php

Comment: I don't know your code, how you pass the words. I try to make you and example if you publish your code I can check it.

Comment: you also view it here, it did not allow me to paste the whole code ------ http://livinghisword.org/my%20code.txt

Comment: Ok I saw your code by the way the code is more simple respect what you have in your site. :) a.php should to have just a code that receive the keywords, and execute the query select from your db

Comment: Ok first you are using title... it's wrong.. the column is keywords

Comment: wait I try to copy in my editor in this way is impossible to read your code

Comment: Ok so if you type A which keywords you would to get in a.php ?

Comment: it is actually connected to this site using buttons. When they click on the letter f then all the articles with the keywords that start with f --------------- example fear, faith, form.... http://livinghisword.org/articles.php

Comment: that only provides me the first word inside the keywords column with the letter a. The rest of the words that start with a do not appear when I use that. The same with '%f' letter in the list of the keyword column row. I'm starting to think you cannot pull words with first letter selection only and omit the rest of the word, hmmmm ------ I wish there was a WHERE clause or HAVING clause that picks the first letter from each word within that row. (example red, fear, safe) It will pull the word fear and not safe. Even though both words have the letter f, I only need the first letter of each word

Comment: Ok got your point.. sorry for missunderstand your needs try with like CONCAT(f, '%')

Comment: where would I place this in my code? http://livinghisword.org/my%20code.txt

Comment: $query = "SELECT keywords, title, link, datesimple FROM articles WHERE keywords LIKE CONCAT('f', '%') ORDER BY..... and check if get only the word that start with f

Comment: That did not work, thank you for trying. I went a different direction until I complete my degree in I.T. to help me accomplish this. You have been a great help and I appreciate your help. Thank you!!!